# Unable to start server because of dependency issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server

hello I am trying to run the npm server for a reactJS app and I am having trouble in doing so. I dont know what I am doing wrong because I am following the instructions given by the terminal.

I have tried to get rid of the webpack dependency and the node modules and tried running the npm start.

package.json

```
    {
      "name": "caregiver",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.7.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
        "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not ie <= 11",
        "not op_mini all"
      ]
    }
```

Error comments that are being outputted.

```
    > caregiver@0.1.0 start /Users/JafferSyed/Desktop/MainProjects/caregiver
    > react-scripts start


    There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
    It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

    The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

      "webpack": "4.19.1"

    Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
    However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

      /Users/JafferSyed/node_modules/webpack (version: 4.28.2)

    Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

    If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
    That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

    To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

      1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
      2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
      3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
      4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

    In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
    If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

      5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
        This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

      6. Check if /Users/JafferSyed/node_modules/webpack is outside your project directory.
        For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

      7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
        This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.

    If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
    That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

    P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!
```

It is supposed to have npm start run a server and display the app on a localhost or a live server.

Comment: Did you try any of the steps listed in the error message?

Comment: yes I tried Deleted the node modules file and the package.json, and there were no webpack in my dependency and then I ran npm install @zero298

Comment: Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a `npm install` from your current project folder. Npm is actually using your user folder `node_modules` (parent folder) instead of your project's `node_modules`.

Comment: I am confused on how to run npm install from my current project folder. I ran it in my terminal after the npx create-react-app .

Comment: You have to ```cd``` into the folder ```create-react-app``` just created.

Comment: If it was ```create-react-app my-react-app``` do ```cd my-react-app``` and then ```npm install```

Comment: so in my case in my terminal I would run `cd User/JafferSyed/Desktop/MainProjects /caregiver`

Comment: Yes, and then ```npm i```

Comment: (it should have been installed by default, but try). You can also remove the folder ```/Users/JafferSyed/node_modules``` if you are not using for anything else.